# error trying to make function for counting friends

Tags: mysql, sql

Error: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
code:

```
USE `my_first_db`;
DROP function IF EXISTS `show_users_firends_count`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `my_first_db`$$
CREATE FUNCTION `show_users_firends_count` (ff int)
RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
Select
  count(user_friend.user_id + user_friend.friend_id)
From
  user_friend
Where
  user_friend.user_id = ff;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do by summing two integer values within a `count()`  aggregation? Sample data and desired results would help clarifying your question.

Answer (score 0):

You had it almost right.

A functions ahs to return something so you send the count back.

You should check the query anyway. your count doesn't look right. because you add useid and freind_id and count that, that is wrong. so check the query and change it. it now count  all friends_id that are connected to a user_id

```
DROP function IF EXISTS `show_users_friends_count`;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `show_users_friends_count` (ff int)
RETURNS int
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
Select
  count(user_friend.friend_id) INTO @count
From
  user_friend
Where
  user_friend.user_id = ff;
RETURN @count;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```